# Typescript compiler errors when using with Context Provider API - React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am planning to implement a theme changer and would like to store the color selected by the user in the context. When I pass data to the value prop of the Context.Provider, I get an error `TS2739: Type 'Readonly<{}>' is missing the following properties from type 'ThemeContextType': color, onChangeTheme`. Please advice. This is what I have.

```
class App extends Component {
  private onChangeTheme = (color: string) => this.setState({ color });

  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      color: Colors.BLUE3,
      onChangeTheme: this.onChangeTheme,
    };
  }

  public render() {
    return (
            <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state}>
              <Routes />
            </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }

}
```

ThemeContext.ts

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

type ThemeContextType = {
  color: string;
  onChangeTheme: (value: string) => void;
};

export const ThemeContext = createContext<ThemeContextType | undefined>(
  undefined
);
```

Error Message:

> TS2739: Type 'Readonly<{}>' is missing the following properties from type 'ThemeContextType': color, onChangeTheme  index.d.ts(337, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<ThemeContextType | undefined>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app component doesn't specify the type on its state, so it defaults to `{}`. Change this:

```
class App extends Component {
```

To this:

```
interface AppState {
  color: string;
  onChangeTheme: (value: string) => void;
}

class App extends Component<{}, AppState> {
```

Or since that AppState is identical to ThemeContextType, you could do:

```
class App extends Component<{}, ThemeContextType> {
```

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same problem but with functional components. I cannot pass the setter function of a usestate to the value in the context provider. many thanks